# Mercurial equivalent to hg qdiff?

Tags: mercurial, diff

[mq](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension), which I like a lot, but which I understand is being deprecated in favor of [changeset evolution](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution), provides a command `hg qdiff` that shows the combination of the last-saved patch mixed with the current working directory diffs.  *I.e.*, it shows what will be the content of the complete patch if I enter `hg commit --amend` right now.

Is there a way to show the combined diff like that in base (non-mq) mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the answer as I prepared to submit the question: `hg diff` with respect to the parent of the current change:

```
hg diff -r '.^'
```